# Jade Templates - Dynamically Calling a Mixin

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, pug

How can I use a string from the json being fed into a Jade template to dynamically load a mixin? Below, the goal is for `twoColumn.jade` to load the `foo` and `bar` mixins.

**twoColumn.jade**

```
mixin twoColumns(obj)
    .container-fluid
        .row(class=obj.class)
            for item in obj.items
                .col-xs-12.col-sm-3
                    //- Syntax for dynamically calling a mixin?
                    +item.template(item)
```

**content.json**

```
{
    "twoColumns": {
        "class": "foobar",
        "items": [
            {
                "template": "foo",
                "title": "Hello"     
            },
            {
                "template": "bar",
                "title": "World"     
            }
        ]            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature that is not very obvious in Jade, as it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation. You can actually use the interpolation syntax (`#{...}`) for dynamically choosing the `mixin` name.

From the [Jade language guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade-language.md):

> interpolation? yup! both types of text can utilize interpolation, if we passed `{ name: 'tj', email: 'tj@vision-media.ca' }` to the compiled function we can do the following:
>
> ```
> #user #{name} &lt;#{email}&gt;
> ```
>
> outputs `<div id="user">tj &lt;tj@vision-media.ca&gt;</div>`

Example usage:

```
mixin foo(item)
  p Foo called

mixin bar(item)
  p Bar called

mixin twoColumns(obj)
  .container-fluid
    .row(class=obj.class)
      for item in obj.items
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-3
          +#{item.template}(item)
```