# How to pass jade expression as mixin argument?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a simple jade mixin:

```
mixin event(title)
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading !{title}
      .panel-body 
        if block
          block
        else
          p No content provided
```

I can call it that way:

```
  - var title = "<a href='profile/@Carl'> @Carl</a>"

  +event ( title )
    | It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
    | because I feel so much better now.
    br
    | Really. Thank god, it's over
```

But what I want to do is to use jade expression for the title like this:

```
  - var title = a(href='profile/@Carl') @Carl

  +event ( title )
    | It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
    | because I feel so much better now.
    br
    | Really. Thank god, it's over
```

But jade doesn't like this and returns an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (191:43)
```

**Is there any way to achieve that?**

> Note the line 43 mentioned in the error doesn't exist in the file. This is suspicious

Comment: See also [#631 Allow multiple blocks to be defined inside mixins and includes](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems passing html as a string like your current solution is the only way. 
Parameters to a mixin should be js expression

Comment: No way to store the result of a jade expression into a string (instead of outputting it)?

Comment: @Nameiscarl, As I know, there is no way how to do that. I also tried to google and didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

The info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24392426/675721) led to a solution that worked for me...

You can make your title a mixin, and dynamically call your mixin

```
mixin event(title)
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading 
      +#{title}
    .panel-body 
      if block
        block
      else
        p No content provided

mixin title 
  a(href='profile/@Carl') @Carl

+event("title")
  | It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
  | because I feel so much better now.
  br
  | Really. Thank god, it's over
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
mixin event   
  block

  mixin contentDefault
    p No content provided

  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      +heading
    .panel-body
      +content

+event
  mixin heading
    a(href='profile/@Carl') @Carl
  mixin content
    |.
      It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
      because I feel so much better now.
    br
    | Really. Thank god, it's over

+event
  mixin heading
    | Timothy
  mixin content
    +contentDefault
```

From https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/631#issuecomment-70590841

(SO's syntax highlighting sucks BTW)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done.

```
//- Helper mixin to call a function or display straight text
mixin funcstr(f)
  | !{typeof f=="function"?(f.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments,1)),''):''+f}

//- Original event mixin with special title
mixin event(title)
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        //- Also illustrating passing params. Could call multiple times with different params here.
        +funcstr(title,'invoke param','other data')
      .panel-body 
        if block
          block
        else
          p No content provided
```

Then:

```
//- Usage of event without passing function
+event("hello")
  | Some text here
```

produces:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">hello
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body"> Some text here
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
//- Function to produce a title with a link, parameterized with a name
-function myTitle(name){return function(){
  a(href='profile/@#{name}') @#{name}
-}}

//- Usage of event with passing a function
+event(myTitle('Carl'))
  | It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
  | because I feel so much better now.
  br
  | Really. Thank god, it's over
```

produces:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><a href="profile/@Carl">@Carl</a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body"> 
    It wasn't that hard. But all in all I'm glad I did it
    because I feel so much better now.<br/>Really. Thank god, it's over
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
//-Functions can also be easily nested
-function moreTitle(name){return function(){ //Alternatively, binding also works nice
  div Profile link: #[+funcstr(myTitle(name))]. Enjoy.
  if (arguments.length)
    div Got passed '#{[].slice.call(arguments).join("', '")}'
  else
    div No params at final call time...
-}}

+event(moreTitle('Fred'))
  | There's really no reason to say more...
```

produces:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div>Profile link: <a href="profile/@Fred">@Fred</a>. Enjoy.
    </div>
    <div>Got passed 'invoke param', 'other data'</div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-body"> There's really no reason to say more...
  </div>
</div>
```

In short, you can turn any Jade into a function by wrapping it in some JS.

Note that the Jade code in the function produces output, but this output is not returned from the function. Instead, it's pushed to the output stream. This can lead to strange results:

```
-function info(){
| Great info!
-}

//Invoke and insert result into line (note: result is undefined: info() returns nothing)
//Invocation appends "Great info!" to the output. Afterward, "Important: " is appended to the output.
div Important: #{info()}

//Don't invoke until after "Important: " has been output. Invocation then appends "Great info!".
div Important: #[-info()]
```

produces:

```
<!--Invoke and insert result into line (note: result is undefined: info() returns nothing)-->
<!--Invocation appends "Great info!" to the output. Afterward, "Important: " is appended to the output.-->
<div>Great info!Important: </div>
<!--Don't invoke until after "Important: " has been output. Invocation then appends "Great info!".-->
<div>Important: Great info!
</div>
```

So, be aware of how you call your own functions when they have Jade mixed in.

The example functions have no return statements, but you can of course also return anything from the function and do with it what you like.

Finally, it's possible to capture Jade blocks in a variable. It relies on Jade placing output in an array called "buf", so it's a hack as this could change any time.

```
mixin capture(callback)
  - var s=buf,r;buf=[];
  block
  - r=buf.join('');buf=s;callback(r);

-var someHtml
+capture(function(captured){someHtml=captured})

  div
    h1 A Heading
    p A paragraph!


| Here's some html: !{someHtml}
| I captured it.
```

produces:

```
Here's some html: 
<div>
  <h1>A Heading</h1>
  <p>A paragraph!</p>
</div>
I captured it.
```