# Jade dynamic mixin call not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Currently I have 2 mixins that I'm looking at adding more onto. These mixins may show up in other mixins, but they may not.

Looking at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392055/jade-templates-dynamically-calling-a-mixin), I tried the following

```
+#{displayType}(group[fieldName])
```

However that doesn't seem to parse.

I would like to avoid

```
case displayType
  when boolSimpleStatus
    +boolSimpleStatus(group[fieldName])
  when boolCheckBox
    +boolCheckBox(group[fieldName])
```

Altogether my mixin is

```
mixin boolean_table_cell(fieldName, group, displayType)
  +data_table_cell(fieldName)
  +#{displayType}(group[fieldName])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far as I know, interpolation works with args you pass to the compiled template. In your case, displayType is an argument to the mixin and that's why it is not working. You can remove the argument from the mixin and pass it via the call to render function like this res.render(whatevertemplate, {displayType: whatevertype}) and interpolation should work with that